# Kubernetes - Is it possible to combine Pod.yaml and Service.yaml in one yaml file (but without Deployment)

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-pod

I have two different YAMLs one for **Pod** and one for **Service**.
Is it possible to combine them into one YAML but not to use **Deployment** kind YAML in which I know we can specify both Pod and Service definition but I do not need to worry about replicas etc.
Is it possible to combine them together? I haven't find such example/ guidance in documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287850/how-to-have-multiple-object-types-in-a-single-openshift-yaml-template

Comment: (Even if you don't want multiple replicas, you should still use a Deployment, since you can't change a Pod after it's created.  A Deployment also knows how to update itself, temporarily running two Pods concurrently, without causing service downtime.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can put whatever resources you want in a yaml file, you just need to separate them with three dashes e.g:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Service

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Pod
```

Comment: Thank you!
Is the order important? Should I define some dependency between them as well or probably that is not needed?

Comment: Either order is fine.  The dependency is implicit by the pod's labels and the service's selector, and it doesn't matter which one is deployed first.

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate objects in a single YAML, separating them with `---`

Something like:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
...
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
...
```

You may want to create a Deployment first, figuring out what your Pod definition should look like.

Order shouldn't matter, though depending on the client loading it, failure may or may not stop applying the rest of the objects -- kubectl would apply everything it can.

Comment: Thank you this clarifies

Answer (score 2):

What are you intending to do with this yaml file?  'kubectl create'?

You can separate objects by a line of 3 hyphens: '---'.